# Un-installing excel add-in

Tags: excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

We developed an excel add-in which is live in the Microsoft store. Adding the add-in from the store works fine, but uninstalling the add-in through excel web version is failing with following error in the console (Tried in chrome/safari browser). Uninstalling works fine in desktop version.

Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Not sure why 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' is getting invoked during removing an add-in. Any specific reasons?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching us. Can I know which Add-in you are seeing this error ? It's definitely not right to have this error, if you can provide a repro video, that will be helpful for us to better understand your scenario.

Comment: Is there a way to share the recorded video with you privately

Comment: Can your share the add-in name or public repro video? This problem is not owned by our team, but I probably know which team is responsible, I can help transfer it to him. So better to provide more information to help locate the issue.

Comment: I've contacted the Microsoft support team. They are looking into it. Once problem is identified I'll update on this.

Comment: okay, feel free to let me know if you need me.